I faced this problem after installing some dependencies
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_updatedFibers' on number '0'
    at requestUpdateLane (chunk-BN7ZACJ3.js?v=9cf9493f:18505:43)
    at updateContainer (chunk-BN7ZACJ3.js?v=9cf9493f:20742:22)
    at ReactDOMHydrationRoot.render.ReactDOMRoot.render (chunk-BN7ZACJ3.js?v=9cf9493f:21113:11)
    at main.jsx:6:45

I was trying to use Bootstrap dropdown menu and it was not working so I tried installing the following dependencies:
npm install bootstrap jquery popper.js
npm install react@^17.0.2
npm install react-swipeable-views@latest
npm install --force

and that has brought the error
